# Is there a better way to do lots of if else statements for joystick input

Tags: java

I am making an input for an controller and translating is to WASD input. It took me many if else statements and I thought it could use some improvements. What are possible solutions to make it shorter or make it better.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Translator {
    private Robot r;

    public Translator(){
        try {
            r = new Robot();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void KeyHandler(double x, double y, boolean pressing){
        ReleaseAll();
        if((x > 1250 && x <2750) && y < 500){
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        } else if ((x > 1250 && x <2750) && y >3500){
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        } else if(x < 600 && (y > 1000 && y < 3000 )){
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        } else if(x > 3250 && (y > 1000 && y < 3000 )){
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        }else if(x < 1500 && y < 1000){
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        } else if(x > 2750 && y < 1000){
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        } else if(x > 2750 && y > 3000){
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        } else if(x < 1500 && y > 3000){
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        } else {
            ReleaseAll();
        }

        if(pressing){
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseAll(){
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a direct answer to your question but it might help somewhat, it depends on how much energy you would like to put into changing the way you check the x and y positions.

But I am thinking that a classic search algorithm would be suited for the task. In your case, you are essentially checking every single possible outcome one by one, a comparison would be to search a list for say a specific string by going over each value one by one.

What your could do is instead to check whether your values are less or greater than the middle value. This would leave you with just half the values to check in the next iteration, and then you keep narrowing the scope down until you in which "section" of possible values the input belongs to.

What I am talking about here is called "Binary Search", the fact that you have 2 dimension in you data does makes things more complicated, and it would be up to you to also adapt the algorithm in order for it to work on your dataset of possible values in both x and y.

You can find a more extensive explanation of different search-algorithms here:

https://stackabuse.com/search-algorithms-in-java/